# ivh-treeview disable the checkbox for the first node

Tags: angularjs, forms, web, frontend

I am using the `IVHTREEVIEW` in one of our application. Our tree-view is something like below:

```
+ click + to see all items in list
Item
Item1.1
Item2
Item2.2
```

We display the checkbox for each item. For the enduser a checkbox for the first node 'Click + to see all Items in list' doesn't make sense in our business. I need to disable or hide the `CHECKBOX` only for that node( 'Click + to see all Items in list'). How can I do this?

I tried to use 'useCheckboxes' and set it to false, in the below function of ivh-treeview.js. But it is not working.

Can you tell me how we can achieve this?

```
trvw.label = function(node) {
trvw.label = function(node) { if(node[localOpts.labelAttribute] == "Click + to see all Items in list"){
node[localOpts.useCheckboxes] = false; } return node[localOpts.labelAttribute];};
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a custom node template and take advantage of the `depth`  scope variable that ivhTreeview provides.

In your template: `<div ng-if="depth > 0" ivh-treeview-checkbox></div>`

Here's a working demo: http://jsbin.com/sadoguv/2/edit?html,js,output

And the docs for the supported scope variables in node templates: https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/blob/master/docs/templates-and-skins.md#supported-template-scope-variables

Comment: Thanks Russell. Assuming this is my DIV. How do I use <div ng-if="depth > 0" here:                                                                                <div class="occupation-list"
 data-ivh-treeview="occupations"
 data-ivh-treeview-id-attribute="'occupationCode'"
 data-ivh-treeview-label-attribute="'occupationName'"
 data-ivh-treeview-children-attribute="'children'"
 data-ivh-treeview-selected-attribute="'isSelected'"
 data-ivh-treeview-expand-to-depth="-1">
</script>

Comment: I fixed it myself. Thanks!